# Linker can't find function definitions, LNK2001 unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, linker, unresolved-external

Here is my simple setup: (i've hidden lots of unneeded information)

```
//AutoFocusTest.h
#include "camAVTEx.h"

class CAutoFocusTestApp : public CWinApp
{
protected:
    camera_t* mCamera;

public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();
};

//camAVTEx.h
class camera_avtcam_ex_t : public camera_t
{
public:
    camera_avtcam_ex_t();
    virtual ~camera_avtcam_ex_t();

    //member variables

    //member function declarations
}

//camAVTEx.cpp
#include "camAVTEx.h"

camera_avtcam_ex_t::camera_avtcam_ex_t()
{
    //stuff
}

camera_avtcam_ex_t::~camera_avtcam_ex_t()
{
    //stuff
}

//the rest are defined here in my program

//AutoFocusTest.cpp
#include AutoFocusTest.h

BOOL CAutoFocusTestApp::InitInstance()
{
    mCamera = new camera_avtcam_ex_t();
}
```

This setup produces the error:

> 3>AutoFocusTest.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol 
>          "public: __cdecl camera_avtcam_ex_t::camera_avtcam_ex_t(void)"
>          (??0camera_avtcam_ex_t@@QEAA@XZ)

From everything I've read on this relatively common problem, I have not linked something causing my camera_avtcam_ex_t function definitions to not be found.  However, I can't figure out what I could have missed. I have added all of the include directories and library directories, as well as added the library files to the additional dependencies section.

Can anyone spot anything that I might be missing?

Comment: You mean surely mCamera = new camera_avtcam_ex_t(); or not?

Comment: `////class function definitions` doesn't actually define the functions, you know that, right?

Comment: Definitions of default constructor and destructor. Specifically, the error you posted mentions the default constructor of `camera_avtcam_ex_t`.

Comment: @duDE why would that matter?

Comment: @duDE yes sorry, i just typed it wrong here

Comment: @LuchianGrigore yes i do. i just didnt wanna type 20 functions like `camera_avtcam_ex_t::camera_avtcam_ex_t(){ blah blah }; camera_avtcam_ex_t::Whatever(){ blahblahblah };` when it could easily be implied that that's what i really did

Comment: What's the command you invoke to build?

Comment: @jrok I just hit F7, which is just a standard build.  I've done several clean/rebuilds too, however and those didnt work either.

Comment: Do you have this `camAVTEx.cpp` file actually added to your project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unresolved external symbol, cannot figure out why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523034/unresolved-external-symbol-cannot-figure-out-why)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have **defined** the constructor for your `camera_avtcam_ex_t`, it's **declared** as `private`, you can't instantiate it.

Comment: No it's public, i just forgot to specify that as I typed the question.