# Unresolved external symbol, cannot figure out why

Tags: c++, object, inheritance, linker, unresolved-external

I have two files that are causing me a lot of grief: `camAVTEx.h` and `camAVTEx.cpp`. Here is the general setup for the two files:

---

```
//.h////////////////////////////////////////////////

/*
#includes to some other files
*/

class camera_avtcam_ex_t : public camera_t
{
public:
    camera_avtcam_ex_t();
    virtual ~camera_avtcam_ex_t();

private:
    //some members

public:
    //some methods

};

void GlobalShutdownVimbaSystem();
```

---

```
//.cpp/////////////////////////////////////////////

#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "camAVTEx.h"

//some other #includes

camera_avtcam_ex_t::camera_avtcam_ex_t()
{
}

//rest of the class' functions

void GlobalShutdownVimbaSystem()
{
    //implememtation
}
```

---

Then, in a file in a different directory, I do a #include to the exact location of the .h file and try to use the class:

---

```
//otherfile.cpp

#include "..\..\src\HardSupport\Camera.h"
//this is the base camera class (camera_t)

#include "..\..\src\HardControl\camAVTEx.h" 
//this is indeed where both the .h and .cpp files are located

void InitCam
{
    camera_t* maincam = new camera_avtcam_ex_t();
}

void OnExit()
{
    GlobalShutdownVimbaSystem();
}
```

When I compile, I get the following errors:

> 8>otherfile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl 
>      camera_avtcam_ex_t::camera_avtcam_ex_t(void)" (??0camera_avtcam_ex_t@@QEAA@XZ)
>
> 8>otherfile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl 
>      GlobalShutdownVimbaSystem(void)" (?GlobalShutdownVimbaSystem@@YAXXZ)
>
> 8>....\bin\x64\Release\otherfile.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

I cannot for the life of me figure out why it can't find the implementations for these two functions.

So I guess my question is fairly obvious:  Why am I getting these errors and what do I need to change to fix them?

Comment: are you sure the file has access to the include files in your program? It could be a possibility your file can't find those includes/

Comment: fairly obvious, but are you sure that `camAVTEx.cpp` is compiled and linked along your `otherfile.cpp` file ? What is your build system ?

Comment: @Need4Sleep I don't see how it couldn't have access

Comment: It's because CamAVTex.o is not being linked into your executable. It's nothing to do with the #include files.

Comment: @Offirmo camAVTEx.obj gets compiled before the otherfile.obj

Comment: can you include the command line that invokes the linker?

Comment: #Roddy So...what do I do to fix that?

Comment: @xcdemon05 - Isn't this the same question you asked in March???

Comment: No this is a different instance of a similar problem.  I resolved that issue but that solution didn't work for this problem.

Comment: @xcdemon05 - that will depend on your platform/compiler/IDE/Build tools - none of which you've mentioned. Visual Studio, I'm guessing?

Comment: Yep, VS2010, windows 7

Comment: As Roddy said, the object file is probably not being linked. The question is where this is compiled. If it's in a library, you need to link that, otherwise just add the .cpp file to the VC project.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever how you look at it, the error you have : `unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl camera_avtcam_ex_t::camera_avtcam_ex_t(void)" (??0camera_avtcam_ex_t@@QEAA@XZ)` means that the compiler knows the symbol `camera_avtcam_ex_t::camera_avtcam_ex_` (that's the class constructor) since he saw its declaration in the `camAVTEx.h` file but halas, it can't find (= resolve) the implementation of this symbol (in short, the code).

This usually happen because of several possible causes :

- you didn't tell the compiler about the code (.cpp) you try to use so he doesn't know it. Try to add the file to your project.
- you compile the missing code, but don't link with it. Check if you don't have two separated projects or try to add the lib to your project if it comes from a lib.
- in some way, the compiled code does not match its definition (happens when mixing C and C++ or messing with namespaces) Check if you are not declaring contradicting enclosing namespaces.
- (maybe other reasons I don't know ?)

Comment: I feel like my issue here may be your second bullet point.  I'm not very good with linker settings yet, any idea how I would go about doing this in VS2010?